# Como poner un activity sobre otro activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Estoy desarrollando una app que al momento de presionar un boton flotante quiero que me salga otro activity encima.

Algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Utiliza los fragments no activitys, sería un activity con varios fragments y se pueden superponer

Comment: Por si acaso tendras una pagina o un tutorial donde me explique con que propiedades superponer ese fragment si no fuera molestia, y gracias @denifer santiago fernandez :D

Comment: También puedes con layouts

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64469/como-superponer-un-layout-encima-de-otro-layout

Comment: Listo, gracias nuevamente (y)

Comment: busca tutoriales como DialogFragments

Answer (score 0):

si quieres usar Activity

puedes definir tu segunda actividad como   Dialog

ejemplo

```
            <activity
            android:name=".actEjemplo"
            android:label="Ejemplo"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
```